# How to building function for codeigniter such as Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, function, helper

I fetch data to views, with **$article['article_title']** is article title

```
<?php
foreach ($articles as $article)
{
?>
    <a href="#"><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></a>
    <!-- some code here -->
<?
}
?>
```

How to create a helper to using **the_title()** (same wordpress function) replace for **$article['article_title']**;

```
<?php
foreach ($articles as $article)
{
?>
    <a href="#"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a>
    <!-- some code here -->
<?
}
?>
```

I created a function working with id (segment), but homepage don't working because it not segment.

Comment: This is the purpose of `models`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a good question.

You can do it this way:

create a helper e.g.:

```
function the_title() 
{
    $ci =& get_instance();

    // if your url looks like http://localhost/this-is-my-page-name
    $slug = $ci->uri->segment(1);


    if($slug) {
        $query = $ci->db->where('slug', $slug)->get('pages')->row();
        $result = $query->title;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and then you can use it in your article like:

```
<?php echo the_title(); ?>
```

Btw. my example is for one result, if you want a list of aricles via foreach loop you will need to modify th code.